# VueJS - Pass variable to this.{variable}

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I would like to have a property dynamically accessed with a variable.

For example, I have :

```
data(){
    redsection : '',
    bluesection : '',
},
methods(){
     changeColor(color, val){
          this.{color+"section"} = val;
     }
}
```

And what I'm trying to do it have a function in the view:

```
<button @click="changeColor("blue", "bar")>blue</button>
<button @click="changeColor("red", "bar")>blue</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an indexer.

```
this[color+"section"] = val;
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WjZNgr?editors=1010).

Answer (score 2):

You could also change it up a bit if you want to make it prettier, like this:

```
data(){
     section: {
          red : 'red',
          blue : 'blue'
     }
},
methods(){
     changeColor(color, val){
          this.section[color] = val;
     }
}
```